# Remove all null entries from generic list of Object

Tags: c#, list, object, generics

This one should be easy, but seems to be eluding me.

Given this variable: (which contains ~30 records)

```
var seriesData = new List<List<object>>();
```

How do I loop through every record, and omit any record that contains a null, anywhere inside?

Typically, each list inside will look like one of the following:

```
["02/16/2019", 5, 7, 10]
["02/17/2019", 3, 15, 2]
```

and sometimes:

```
["02/18/2019", 5, {null}, 10]
```

This is what I have tried, but, it's not working:

```
foreach (List<object> row in seriesData)
{
    if (row.Contains(null)) seriesData.Remove(row);
}
```

The result I'm ending up with is completely empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `RemoveAll` which accepts predicate:

```
seriesData.RemoveAll(row => row.Any(x => x == null))
```

Comment: That's prolly the most elegant solution! I like it the most :)

Comment: Note you can also use pattern match against null if that looks more elegant for you `x => x is null`

Comment: And we have a winner!!  Thank you so much!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use LINQ, this should be easy:

```
seriesData = seriesData
    // filter the lists (x) where all items in them (y) are not null
    .Where(x => x.All(y => y != null))
    // and get the result
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Beautiful, I will try this now!

Comment: This unfortunately didn't actually remove the null entries.  (The null lists)

Comment: @Penjimon You didn't mention that lists themselves could be null

Answer (score 2):

Without LinQ, you may do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < seriesData.Count)
{
    if (seriesData[i].Contains(null))
    {
        seriesData.RemoveAt(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

This may very well be the most performant solution and not require LinQ if you don't use it already. If, on the other hand, you already use LinQ, then style may be more important than performance.

As an exercise, I write a version that changes the order of entries but has a lower complexity. As stated by @Lee, the above code may have an O(n^2) complexity. Here is another version, maybe some benchmarking if performance is really important would help:

```
int i = 0, last;
while (i < seriesData.Count)
{
    if (seriesData[i].Contains(null))
    {
        last = seriesData.Count - 1;
        seriesData[i] = seriesData[last];
        seriesData.RemoveAt(last);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely thought. I'm even surprised the OP doesn't get an exception with that `foreach`

Comment: This is quite inefficient, O(n ^ 2) in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat. Here is yet another one that doesn't modify your original list:

```
var nonulls = seriesData.Where(sd => !sd.Any(o => o == null));
```